# how to configure Apache to redirect test.com to test.com/admin

Tags: apache

How do I configure Apache to redirect test.com to test.com/admin ?

I would prefer to use mod_rewrite but it is not required.  All the posts I see on Apache redirection seems to focus on redirecting all uri's to a single uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mod_rewrite, you can just do `RewriteRule ^$ admin`. That will redirect `/` to `/admin`.

Comment: Thanks.  Is '^$' a regex then?

Comment: No problem. Yes, `^$` is a regex, it just means an empty string. The `^` represents the start of the string and the `$` the end of the string. Therefore it will only match, start of string immediately followed by the end of the string.